# How to get the qualified name of the currently executing function?

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.3 introduced the `__qualname__` attribute for function objects and class objects.

It's easy to get the (unqualified) name and a code object for the currently executing function.

But how to get the qualified name for the currently executing function?

Comment: Inspection. I can get frame objects and code objects. But I can't get a function object which would yield `__qualname__`.

Comment: When you say (unqualified) name do you mean `__name__`?

Comment: for e.g. the frame object the unqualified name is `inspect.stack()[0][0].f_code.co_name`.

Comment: For e.g. function f2 nested in function f1, being a method of class c2 nested in class c1 the qualified name would be: `c1.c2.f1.<locals>.f2`.

For me even better would be: `c1.c2.f1.f2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`executing`](https://github.com/alexmojaki/executing#getting-the-__qualname__-of-the-current-function):

```
executing.Source.for_frame(frame).code_qualname(frame.f_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, currently; see [this thread](http://www.all-mail-archive.com/thread/609021/Re-Python-ideas-Standard-way-to-get-caller-name-and-easy-call-stack-access/1).

[Issue 13672](http://bugs.python.org/issue13672) requests adding `co_qualname` to code objects, and [issue 12857](http://bugs.python.org/issue12857) requests making the called function available through the frame object.  Both have patches attached.

Comment: Thanks. Python inspection is a patchwork and more clumsy than useful IMHO. But perhaps the underlying architecture is the clumsy patchwork?

Comment: @carpetemporem Part of the problem is that inspection has to work on top of multiple implementations which differ quite severely: CPython, Jython, IronPython, PyPy and even Stackless.

Comment: Yep, legacy code. But IMHO Python 3 could have been a chance for a fundamental redesign of a language which was simple and not bad for a starter but becomes more and more of a mess. Chance lost.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.11 this is now possible via:

```
inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_qualname
```

(with optional `.f_back`s inserted before the `.f_code` as desired)

https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/datamodel.html#codeobject.co_qualname