# Determine static method qualified name from within itself in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, introspection

I'm refactoring some code I wrote to work with an interactive TUI and I wish to use my class structure to create commands rather than explicitly typing out strings. Using `__qualname__` would be very handy, but I can't find the equivalent way to call it from within the function?

```py
# Example:
class file:
    class export:
        @staticmethod
        def ascii(output_path):
            return f"/file/export/ascii/ {output_path}"

# Desired
import inspect
class file:
    class export:
        @staticmethod
        def ascii(output_path):
            qualname= inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_qualname  # <-- co_qualname is not implemented
            return f"/{qualname.replace(".", "/")}/ {output_path}"
```

I understand from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514318 that `inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name` will only return `'ascii'` and `co_qual_name` has not been implemented yet per https://stackoverflow.com/a/12213690 and https://bugs.python.org/issue13672?

Is there a way I can get `file.export.ascii` from within the `ascii()` static method itself? Decorators or other design patterns are also an option, but I sadly have hundreds of these static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want by making `ascii` be a class method rather than a static method.  You still call it the same way, but you have a way of accessing the method itself from within the method.

```
class file:
    class export:
        @classmethod
        def ascii(cls, output_path):
            return f"{cls.ascii.__qualname__}/{output_path}"
```

Comment: Neat, I hadn't thought of `@classmethod` as I was only using `@staticmethod` to group similar tui menu functions together. Is there a way to avoid having to write `cls.ascii`?

Comment: You write `cls.ascii` in every copy of the code you write, so it's still the cut-and-paste into every piece of code you put this.  The whole goal is that you need a way to refer to *this specific* method `ascii()`, and certainly not the global function by that name.  So, no, I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as an answer since it solves my design pattern problem